# Define base path for individual tags in swaggo/swag

Tags: go, swagger

I am using https://github.com/swaggo/swag for generating swagger for golang project.
I just want to add multiple base path in swagger doc.
For ex :
My base path is `/api/v1`
I have defined two tags(let say A and B)

Endpoints under tag A will have url like

> localhost:8080/api/v1/getList

Endpoints under tag B will have url like

> localhost:8080/api/v1/sub/getList

I can do this by adding `@router /sub/getList [post]`, but it is not a best practice for adding /sub in all endpoints. So I am searching for solutions like **define basepath for particular tags** or **override the global base path**.

Or is there any way of adding servers like following:

```
"servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://localhost:8080/api/v1/"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://localhost:8080/api/v1/sub/"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: guess you can define something like `@router api/≤version>/sub/getList [post]`, then parse the version inside of the function

Comment: Trying above will result in repeating the `api/sub` tag in all endpoints for that particular tag. Due to that the UI will have lot of repetition which will not be acceptable.